# Generate new sheets from a range and allow for use of "IfElse" from an adjecent range to force what the new sheet should contain

Tags: vba, excel

I found and altered simple code to create new sheets from a master and name the sheets from the range. The code is below and works without error.

I would like to include an adjacent range (`A11`) in the code that will determine that the new/copied sheet will be created using `MasterReport` or `MasterReport2` as the copy from.  If range `A11` has a "P" I would like the new sheet to be copied from `MasterReport` and if range `A11` contains an "S" the new sheet to be copied will be from `MasterReport2`.  `MasterReport` and `MasterReport2` are hidden sheets.

Most likely need to identify a second range and use `IfElse` but where within the current code should this go.  Would like to maintain that the new sheet names will reflect range `C11` values.

```
Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Sheets("ProjectDefinition").Range("c11")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

For Each MyCell In MyRange

    Sheets("MasterReport").Select
    ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value

Next MyCell
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [so]! Here you can discuss buggy code. For enhancing functionality, give it a try and show us where you get stuck! If it is mainly performance gain or refactoring, you are better of at codereview.stackexchange.com. See [ask] and [help/on-topic]!

Comment: Jeeped, Was off this challange for awhile but final used your advice and the direction you provided worked great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of methods to get your optional termplate worksheet but I believe a [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx) will offer the best expandability.

```
Dim myCell As Range, strWSname As String

With Sheets("ProjectDefinition")
    For Each myCell In .Range(.Range("C11"), .Range("C11").End(xlDown))
        Select Case UCase(myCell.Offset(0, -2))
            Case "S"
                strWSname = "MasterReport2"
            Case "P"
                strWSname = "MasterReport"
            Case Else
                strWSname = "MasterReport"   'default
        End Select
        Sheets(strWSname).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = myCell.Value
    Next myCell
End With
```

Comment: Jeeped, I was off this challange for awhile but final used your advice and the direction you provided worked great!   ThanKs